# Derivative operator equality

Tags: integration, derivatives, differential-operators

So for a while now I've been trying to understand something I've read in a paper, but can't get the prove it strictly.
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that $\int f(x,\theta)  f(x,\theta) d x = 1$. Let the arguments be denoted as $x$ and $\theta$. The given a symmetric derivative operator $H$ defined only on the first argument $x$, the Rayleigh–Ritz potential is defined as:
$$ E(\theta) = \frac{\int f(x,\theta) H(f)(x, \theta) dx}{\int f(x,\theta)  f(x,\theta) d x} =  \int f(x,\theta) H(f)(x, \theta) dx$$
Now the paper states the following:
$$ \nabla_\theta(E) (\theta) = 2 \int \nabla_\theta(f)(x,\theta) H(f)(x, \theta) dx $$
To me this is not obvious why its true. Specifically consider when $H=\nabla_x^2$ then we have:
$$ \nabla_\theta(E) (\theta) = \int \nabla_\theta(f)(x,\theta) H(f)(x, \theta) dx + \int f(x,\theta) \nabla_\theta \nabla^2_x(f)(x, \theta) dx $$
Which implies that the following equality always holds:
$$ \int f(x,\theta) \nabla_\theta \nabla^2_x(f)(x, \theta) dx = \int \nabla_\theta(f)(x,\theta) \nabla_{x^2}(f)(x, \theta) dx  $$

It seems that one can move around the argument of the operator? I've tried when using a simple function, for which the integral is analytic and it seems to hold, but can't derive that it is true in general. Any points towards how to prove it?

Comment: Is it not just integration by parts?

Comment: At least that is not obvious to me how to get it with integration by parts since they come up with a different sign.

Comment: No, if you do it twice the sign disappears, right ?